# Composer [UnexpectedValueException] error will trying to use composer to install a github project

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install a Github project using composer and get the following error:

> Composer [UnexpectedValueException]
> Your Github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters: ""

Can anyone explain  what I need to do to correct this error?

I am using the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev \
    vova07/yii2-start yii2-start
```

Thank you.

Comment: The new answer with `composer self-update` was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67828227/470749

Answer (score 89):

I started getting a similar error and the reason was that Github recently changed the format of their auth tokens:

https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-31-authentication-token-format-updates-are-generally-available/

To resolve the error:

1. Find the `composer/auth.json` file (if you're running the project in a container, you'll have to bash into it and find the file in there)
2. Remove its `github.com` entry. Your file will probably look like the following after removing the entry: `{"github-oauth": {}}`
3. Run `composer self-update`. The issue got resolved in version `2.0.12`. See the first item in the changelog for that version here: https://getcomposer.org/changelog/2.0.12

After that, you can restore your `composer/auth.json` file to its initial state as the newer version of composer will recognize the new key format.

Comment: Even if I try self-update I get the same error, I can't do anything

Comment: Did the self-update succeed? SInce that did the trick for me.

Comment: I just had to run the following command: `php /usr/local/bin/composer self-update` from within the container where I have the project running and it worked for me.

Comment: I replaced my `~/.composer/auth.json` with `{}` to get passed the error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38746307/569976 talks about where to find this directory YMMY

Comment: @DarkteK remove the `github-oauth` line from the `~/.config/composer/auth.json` file, run composer self-update and the add the removed line back to auth.json

Comment: composer upgrade was a solution in my case - thanks

Comment: Both `self-update` and `upgrade` do nothing for me and just print the same error.

Comment: I renamed `~/.composer/auth.json` to `auth.json~`, updated Composer, then restored the original filename.

Comment: I renamed `~/.composer/auth.json` to `auth.json~`, updated Composer, then restored the original filename.

Comment: How to know where the auth.json is located?

Answer (score 81):

You can try Basic Auth instead:

**Change this (oauth):**

```
  "github-oauth": {
    "github.com": "ghp_[YOUR-PERSONAL-TOKEN]"
  }
```

**To this (basic auth):**

```
  "http-basic": {
    "github.com": {
      "username": "[YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME]",
      "password": "ghp_[YOUR-PERSONAL-TOKEN]"
    }
  }
```

You can find [instructions on how to create a Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Inspired from [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#non-web-application-flow). Apparently, you can use Basic Authentication with a Personal Access token instead of oauth in some cases (e.g. like mine: installing a private git repo with composer).

Comment: Unless you can update Composer to v2, this is the only working solution. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, I had to update the file `/root/.composer/auth.json` in my Docker container (not on my PC) using an editor like vim, then it worked.

Comment: It worked for me after updating .compoer/auth.json as mentioned

Answer (score 42):

I fixed it.

Goto C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Composer

Open the auth.json

delete the github.com entry under "github-oauth": {}

That's it.

Comment: Composer seem to do a rather aggressive validation on tokens. So aggressive, that updating my GitHub token to the new format yielded this error to me. I was running Composer 2.0.8 and I had to remove the token and update to Composer 2.0.12 and the re-apply the token.

Comment: @NiklasEkman how did you solve it? i tried removing the github.com but it did'nt work. can you shae your structure?

Comment: @Thiago Follow the instructions in the answer above. After you've deleted the  `github-auth` entry, run `composer self-update` and then add whatever you deleted back to the file.

Comment: I've comment an update for this answer, please check.

Comment: File does not exist at the specified location.

Comment: @ruchir.mehta I am receiving this error after applying your solution. Thanks for the location of the file by the way. I was having difficulty in finding. [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "C:/Users/umair/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:
  "github-oauth": {}
  -------------^
  Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

Comment: This is not a solution. If you need authentication, composer will ask for a token and the problem is created again.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem 2 times.

Answer (score 18):

Update answer for Masiorama and Ruchir Mehta:

If you looking for file auth.json but don't know how, use this command:

> locate auth.json

And here's the result:
You can see that ***auth.json*** will look like this:

> /home/{your user name}/.config/composer/auth.json

[image]

Then you could use this command to edit the file:

> sudo gedit /home/dev/.config/composer/auth.json

And remove content inside ***github-oauth***.
[image]

Comment: Does not really help. The next token I generate is invalid too.

Answer (score 14):

If you're on MacOS, the `auth.json` file is at `~/.composer/auth.json`. Then from there, you can remove the value for `github-oauth`. I tried fully deleting the file but I got a parse error, `Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['`. Your `auth.json` file should look like this:

```
{
        "github-oauth": {}
}
```

This is similar to other answers posted but I wasn't able to use the `locate` command on MacOS so this might be helpful to other Mac users

Answer (score 7):

This error recently popped up from nowhere.

Simply deleting the whole auth file worked for me..! Not sure why / when it appeared in the first place.

~/.composer/auth.json

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know (I'm a beginner with composer too), the problem is with your authentication, so you have to fix your credentials in auth.json inside path-to-composer/.composer/

Inside you will find a json which will probably looks like:

```
{
  "github-oauth": {
    "github.com": null
  }
}
```

Fix that and you should be ok ;)

Comment: If you do not know how to fix manually, an easier solution would be to completely erase the auth.json. This way, it will try to recreate the credentials the next time you prepare a project. ;)

Comment: for those on linux looking on the above path: ` ~/.config/composer/auth.json` wrestled a lot with find this today :)

Comment: I've comment an update for this answer, please check.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is just to upgrade your Composer version
using command `composer self-update`.

Comment: Today `composer self-update` didn't work for me even though I think it did in the past since I see that I'd already upvoted this answer. Today https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149438/470749 helped.

Answer (score 3):

Go to C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Composer
Open the auth.json file.
Clear everything and paste the below code

```
{
"bitbucket-oauth": {},
"github-oauth": {},
"gitlab-oauth": {},
"gitlab-token": {},
"http-basic": {},
"bearer": {}
}
```

I hope it will be solved

Comment: this solved my issue.

Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

I run in the same problem after upgrading githup api token to the new format.
The answer is you need to upgrade [composer version 1.10.21](https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/1.10.21) or higher that fixes this problem.

Comment: To give more details, at first, remove the key from file ```~/.composer/auth.json``` => ```"github-oauth": {}```. Then, update composer to the latest needed major version. For instance, if you need version 1: ```composer self-update --1``` and you will be good to go.

Comment: The solution was to change the auth-method like answered here:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041384/2377961

Answer (score 2):

Same solution as the answer of Paulina Khew but with command lines on MacOS :

```
cd ~/.composer/
nano auth.json
```

Delete what is inside th bracket :

```
{
        "github-oauth": {}
}
```

When you're ready to save the file, hold down the `Ctrl key` and press the letter `O`

Press the `Enter` key on your keyboard to save.

When finished, press `Ctrl + X` to close nano and return to your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the composer authentication configuration file `~/.composer/auth.json`

Then replace the following.

```
"http-basic": {
  "github.com": {
    "username": "[YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME]",
    "password": "ghp_[YOUR-PERSONAL-TOKEN]"
  }
}
```

Now run the command `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug.

If you have Debian or Ubuntu, try this patch. Otherwise read the last line.

### Quick copy-paste patch

If you have Debian 10 buster or Ubuntu 20.LTS or similar distributions, try this copy-paste command:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/valerio-bozzolan/84364c28a3bba13751c504214016adcf/raw/c1356d529c89c10de4c959058e2e86ffe58fa407/fix-composer.patch -O /tmp/fix-composer.patch
sudo patch /usr/share/php/Composer/IO/BaseIO.php /tmp/fix-composer.patch
```

If it does not work, write it in the comments.

### Step-by-step explaination

Your Composer version has a bug: you are able to save a valid GitHub token, but then it's not able to read that token again because Composer thinks that your GitHub token cannot contain underscores or stuff like that. Moreover, it's strange that Composer checks its syntax only the second time. Why? that's another story.

The fix is simple. You can temporary disable that wrong validation in your Composer version. Also because GitHub is a proprietary service and their specifications can change over time (as you demonstrated today). So it makes sense not to validate the syntax of GitHub tokens. The only person who should hard-validate GitHub tokens is GitHub itself, not Composer.

If you installed Composer via `apt install composer`, probably you will not have any update available and surely you cannot use `self-update` because Composer is read-only for security reasons (and for a similar reason, you should not execute Composer from `root`). Instead, you can create a safe hot-patch to fix that specific issue.

To create a patch, create a file called `/tmp/fix-composer.patch` with this exact content:

```
103,105c103,105
<             if (!preg_match('{^[.a-z0-9]+$}', $token)) {
<                 throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Your github oauth token for '.$domain.' contains invalid characters: "'.$token.'"');
<             }
---
> //            if (!preg_match('{^[.a-z0-9]+$}', $token)) {
> //                throw new \UnexpectedValueException('Your github oauth token for '.$domain.' contains invalid characters: "'.$token.'"');
> //
```

That content can also be seen from here:

https://gist.github.com/valerio-bozzolan/84364c28a3bba13751c504214016adcf

Then run this command to apply that patch:

```
sudo patch /usr/share/php/Composer/IO/BaseIO.php /tmp/fix-composer.patch
```

If it does not work, probably you have not installed `composer` via `apt`.

---

In short, whatever operating system, and whatever installation method, locate the file `BaseIO.php` in your Composer and comment out the validation check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Composer 1 and Magento is latest version.Than upgrade your composer version 2.

Comment: This does in fact not only affects historic versions in the `--1` channel, but also in the channels of  `--2` and `--2.2`. Updating however is not a bad idea, albeit other answers cover that already. Looks more like a comment to me than an answer.