# Unable to self-update Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to update Composer without any luck!

What I have tried:

```
$ composer self-update
```

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Command "self-update" is not defined.

```
$ sudo -H composer self-update
```

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Command "self-update" is not defined.

```
$ sudo apt-get install composer
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done composer is already the newest version. The
> following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
> required:   libntdb1 linux-headers-4.2.0-30
> linux-headers-4.2.0-30-generic linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic
> linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic python-ntdb Use 'apt-get
> autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
> and 10 not upgraded.

I am trying to self-update Composer because I am facing the following each time I try:

```
$ composer update
```

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
> dependencies (including require-dev)
> [RuntimeException]
> Could not load package rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome in
> http://packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse
> version constraint v4.1     .*: Invalid version string "v4.1.*"
> [UnexpectedValueException]
> Could not parse version constraint v4.1.*: Invalid version string
> "v4.1.*"

How can I fix this issue?

My PHP version is:

```
php --version
```

> PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli)  Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

My composer version is:

```
composer --version
```

> Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (@package_version@)
> @release_date@

Comment: I'd suggest to just uninstall it and install [according to the official docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) (ie not using apt or any package manager)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How did you install composer in the first place?

Comment: sudo -H composer self-update

This command perfectly works in Ubuntu to upgrade composer latest version.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since I posted my answer, I have learnt a new easier way to install Composer programmatically: *[How do I install Composer programmatically?](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-composer-programmatically.md)*

### Old Answer:

---

As per @JimL comment, I was able to self update Composer by:

- Uninstalling Composer from the package manager (apt).
- I installed it according to the [official documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)

Now it works as expected.

Comment: This worked for me, although the "official documentation" is a bit confusing.

Comment: If you have Ubuntu 18.04 you may find some problems with the official installation method. Checkout [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7730)

Comment: The problem with the official documentation is that the process doesn't allow for Composer to be updated automatically with regular OS updates.

Comment: `alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'` This command was also needed at the end to have the composer work from any directory.

Answer (score 113):

As [Waqleh said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772798/unable-to-self-update-composer/37788750#37788750), you have to uninstall PHP Composer and install it again. First, execute:

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

Then, execute these commands. **The checksum here is for Composer 1.10.13, but you'll get the newest Composer (2.0.4 at the moment of editing this answer) when running the first line, so be sure to check in** https://getcomposer.org/download/:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '8a6138e2a05a8c28539c9f0fb361159823655d7ad2deecb371b04a83966c61223adc522b0189079e3e9e277cd72b8897') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Now move file *composer.phar* to a directory that is in your path (from *[Installation - Linux / Unix / macOS](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos)*):

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

And execute `composer` from any directory. That's all!

PS: If you're using [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm) (or maybe other IDEs), you'll have to close it and open it again.

Comment: After that last unlink step, i did: sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

Comment: The checksum is incorrect for the latest version of composer.

Comment: The second command deletes composer-setup.php and the third one fails as a result

Comment: You really need to follow the commands from the documentation because each new release will have a different hash (line two of the commands) and the commands from this answer will fail

Comment: To editors and reviewers: *"[PHP Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software))"* (capital "C") is a proper noun, not a common noun (in this context).

Comment: most recent hash as of 09/09/2021 `756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3` so replace the long string in line 2 with this hash and unless there has been another release since my comment it will verify installer

Comment: After the unlink step, in some cases, you may have to run `source ~/.bashrc`  to make it work in your same terminal.

Comment: `alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer'` This command was also needed at the end to have the composer work from any directory.

Comment: **Quick tip**: Copy the commands from the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/download/), instead of the answer's.

Comment: just ignore the hash. if you are beeing man-in-the-middled, you're having other problems anyway. so just don't use this line

Comment: It might be needed to reboot computer after all steps. And yes use commands from docs as @wranvaud stated. https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: I thought sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer should move the file into the directory composer, so I created that directory in advance. But composer is the renamed phar file, not a directory.

Answer (score 39):

It worked for me (linux, Ubuntu 20.04):

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/download/ says to move it instead to `/usr/local/bin/composer`. I will update your answer.

Comment: this worked for me: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
 sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

Comment: In my case you need to move it to ``sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer`` Instead

Answer (score 35):

**Install the latest version**:

Remove your current Composer version, for example Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

Now, head to https://getcomposer.org/download/ and paste the script in your command line. This ensures that you get the latest version of Composer (as time of writing: v2.5.8).

Like this:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

After some time passed, you can update and there isn't any need to use the **sudo** prefix:

```
composer self-update
```

> Note: The up-to-date hash can be found at getcomposer.org/download

Comment: What can I do if it timesout?

Comment: @Black use vpn to make sure it's not your ISP problem

Comment: Not possible. I am already behind a VPN and can only access the server via this VPN

Comment: Would you open https://getcomposer.org/ ? or antivirus or any staff blocked this site?
and are you sure php install as environment app?

Comment: The up-to-date hash can be found at https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 8):

If you have an old version of Composer you need to follow these commands:

```
composer -V
sudo apt remove composer
cd /tmp
wget http://getcomposer.org/download/1.10.5/composer.phar

php composer.phar -V
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/composer
composer -V
```

Comment: did you mean `chmod 755`

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the installation directory and filename while setting up PHP Composer - `php composer-setup.php` like so:

```
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 2):

Already there are many answers, Would like to share my experience with this.

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04**, and My previous Composer version was **Composer 2.0.11** and my Project requirement was **Composer 2.1.15**.

I didn't had to remove anything, I simply used the following command and it worked fine for me :)

[image: Composer Update]

Answer (score 1):

I've installed [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) and it saves me a lot.

Install brew and then `brew install composer` to install Composer.

Comment: I get "brew not found"

Comment: You've to install brew first before running this command. See https://docs.brew.sh/

Answer (score 1):

**Composer self-update** may not work for others and using the documentation from the composer may be confusing for some. The following steps may help reinstall the composer to solve the problem.

**#update the package manager**

```
sudo apt update
```

**#install the required packages**

```
sudo apt install php-cli unzip
```

**#retrieve the installer**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o /tmp/composer-setup.php
```

**#obtain the latest hash from the Composer page**

```
HASH=`curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig`
echo $HASH #verify the obtained value
```

**#verify that the installation script safety**

```
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', '/tmp/composer-setup.php') === '$HASH') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

**#installing composer globally**

```
sudo php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

**#test your installation**

```
composer
```

**That's it. Credit: [Erika Heidi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-20-04)**

Answer (score 0):

composer 2 on debian :

```
cd /usr/src

sudo apt-get install curl php7.2-cli

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

chmod 777 composer

nano ~/.bashrc
```

add : `PATH=$PATH/usr/local/bin/`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

verify :`composer -v`

Answer (score -2):

### Install the latest Composer by the following steps:

**Uninstalling Composer**

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

**Run following commands**

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '8a6138e2a05a8c28539c9f0fb361159823655d7ad2deecb371b04a83966c61223adc522b0189079e3e9e277cd72b8897') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
```

**Install Composer in the /usr/bin directory to run Composer from anywhere**

```
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

**Remove the installer**

```
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

**To check or self update**

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers - the given steps were posted exactly like that more than a year ago, and your answer does not add any new information

Comment: that was not duplicate they have a different method to perform it but they were doing this incorrect way

Comment: Please share more details about this - as far as I see, A1Gard uses the same commands. If there's something wrong about the other answers, you should explain why yours is better

Comment: they were not installing it in /usr/bin before deleting composer-setup that's why it will not make it global

Comment: Why should such a file be present in `/usr/bin`? According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux, `/usr/bin` should not be used for binaries that you install on any other way than through the package manager

Comment: because it is the composer and we used this in every project and that power is given to us by the composer team itself   sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer,  you can check there official documentation

Comment: And is there anything wrong or incorrect in using `/usr/local/bin`, as suggested in other answers? Please add all such explanation to your answer such that others can see what you are doing differently, and why your different approach is more "correct" than any other

Comment: in other answers, finally, you have to use `php composer.pha` instead of use `composer`. Personally, I add an alias but this solution seems ok (but a warning to use instructions from https://getcomposer.org/dowload/ to have well the last hash is important too !