# Drupal-project requires Composer version 1.0.0 or higher

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I'm using the following composer version, composer -V

```
Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34
```

I tried to do a "composer install" and I get the following error.

```
Drupal-project requires Composer version 1.0.0 or higher. Please update your Composer before continuing.
```

I don't know what should be checked differently on this project to be able to use a development version of composer.

Comment: Did you tried `composer self-update`?

Comment: @rob006 Yes, it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Any errors?

Comment: I meant, it's showing the same error

Comment: Which operating system are you running?
How did you install composer?

Comment: @PascalClaes My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and i installed composer with this link https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest uninstalling composer and re-installing the proper version:

second reply explains it pretty well, use the official documentation to re-install
[Why am I unable to self-update composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772798/why-am-i-unable-to-self-update-composer)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your system to Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), where [the Composer version is >= 1.0.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/composer).