# Composer conflict in a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have recently create a laravel project and when i hit

```
composer install
```

I got error like

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for joshbrw/laravel-module-installer ^0.1.4 -> satisfiable by joshbrw/laravel-module-installer[v0.1.4].
    - joshbrw/laravel-module-installer v0.1.4 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

Composer versions:

```
Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34
```

Any help would be Appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest updating composer itself. Run `composer self-update` and then try `composer install` again.

Comment: Update your composer, the latest version is 1.8.5

Comment: @RossWilson  [InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: run this `composer selfupdate`

Comment: @umefarooq same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772798/unable-to-self-update-composer