# RESOLVE - I can't install something in Symfony with composer

Tags: linux, symfony, ubuntu, package, composer-php

I need some help again about symfony in general.
I try to install mailer to send mail, but when I do **sudo composer require symfony/mailer** I receive this :

> Warning from repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
> Info from repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See getcomposer.org/root for details
> Warning from repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
> Info from repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
> Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.4.*"
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Warning from repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
> Info from repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.4.*"
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
> - doctrine/dbal 3.3.4 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/dbal 3.3.4 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/dbal 3.3.4 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - Installation request for doctrine/dbal (locked at 3.3.4) -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[3.3.4].

> Potential causes:
> -A typo in the package name
> -The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting ; see <getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
> -It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
> Read <hgetcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

So I went in the website of composer, and they say do to this : **sudo composer update** to update the versions, so I did it but I have get the same error :

> Warning from repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
> Info from repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
> Do not run Composer as root/super user! See getcomposer.org/root for details
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Warning from repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
> Info from repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.4.*"
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
> - doctrine/orm 2.13.x-dev requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.12.x-dev requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.12.3 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.12.2 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.12.1 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.12.0 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.11.x-dev requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.11.3 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.11.2 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.11.1 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.11.0 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - doctrine/orm 2.11.2 requires composer-runtime-api ^2 -> no matching package found.
> - Installation request for doctrine/orm ^2.11 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.11.2, 2.11.3, 2.11.x-dev, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.12.2, 2.12.3, 2.12.x-dev, 2.13.x-dev].
> Potential causes:
> -A typo in the package name
> -The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
> see <getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
> -It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
> Read <getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

If someone have a solution, I really appreciate it

Thanks by advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `sudo composer self-update`. When you run `composer update` you are only upgrading the packages in the composer file, not the `composer` executable.

Comment: I have an error : "self-update doesn't exist" when I try your command..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772798/unable-to-self-update-composer

Comment: Hi ! It's all good for me, thanks a lot !