# Why is COMPOSER_HOME empty?

Tags: php, bash, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I have a question about the programming tool [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) which is installed as an executable in `/usr/local/bin/composer` on 3 different machines that I use between work and home. According to:

```sh
composer help global
```

> ```
> COMPOSER_HOME is c:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Composer on Windows
> and /home/<user>/.composer on unix systems.
>
> Note: This path may vary depending on customizations to bin-dir in
> composer.json or the environmental variable COMPOSER_BIN_DIR.
> ```

But both of these are empty:

```sh
echo $COMPOSER_HOME
echo $COMPOSER_BIN_DIR
```

When I run:

```sh
composer global require <package>
```

It installs to `/home/<user>/.config/composer/vendor/bin` *only* on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, but everywhere else it installs appropriately to `/home/<user>/.composer/vendor/bin`

Why is it installing to `~/.config` instead of `~/.composer` and not setting the `COMPOSER_HOME` variable?

I notice this because I source my common dotfiles which includes the global composer bin path. I know I can workaround this by manually setting `COMPOSER_HOME` in my bashrc, but I would rather understand why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/59596ff012c17d209f6bc2186f766033e461c04e/src/Composer/Factory.php#L52) reveals some additional complexity to how Composer's home directory is computed.

If your system uses freedesktop.org standards, which it detects by looking for [environment variables beginning with `XDG_`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables), then Composer uses `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/composer/`, falling back to `$HOME/.config/composer/` if that isn't set.

You might be interested to see that there is a [special case](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/59596ff012c17d209f6bc2186f766033e461c04e/src/Composer/Factory.php#L67-L70): if `$HOME/.composer/` exists and is a directory it will be used in favour of the freedesktop.org logic. Presumably this is for backwards compatibility. If you create this directory manually, Composer should use it.

I'm not sure why this is just affecting your Ubuntu 16.04 machine. My old laptop running a variant of Ubuntu 14.04 uses `XDG_` environment variables.

I suspect that you installed Composer for the first time on that machine after the freedesktop.org logic [was added in July of 2015](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/e8a6cb536bf202b8e36937218117f36d5fffaad3) and that your other machines all had Composer first installed before then. Then their existing `~/.composer/` directories would ensure that Composer kept using that location.

Comment: Nice info, thanks! I'm gonna purge composer and reinstall testing a couple things tomorrow when I get a chance back at work. My other two machines are running 14.04 FYI

Comment: Confirmed, and nice find my friend! I think it's time to update the composer help docs.

Comment: thanks to your input, I submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5575) with updated documentation.

Comment: Seldaek merged [pull request #5575](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5575) into composer:master 5 hours ago. Thanks again for your help!