# Export composer to path on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I want to run the `laravel` command on my machine. But I always get `laravel: command not found`. I do have globally required Laravel on composer. Most people say that you need to add composer to your path via this command: `export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`. But I don't have the directory `~/.composer'`.

The problem is that I can't find the location of composer. Does somebody know the correct location which I need to export to my PATH. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Composer path is likely `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin`. Try adding that instead.

See also [Why is COMPOSER_HOME empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38703915/354577)