# Laravel command not found after adding Composer bin directory to PATH

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, composer-php

I ran `sudo nano .bashrc` and added

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

I restarted my terminal, ran `laravel` and received

```
laravel: command not found
```

I had run this prior to the above

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Also tried executing what I added to `.bashrc` in the terminal directly.

`echo $PATH` prints

```
/home/dev/.composer/vendor/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Why did you use `sudo` here? Are you trying to set the `laravel` command up for your regular user, or for root?

Comment: What happens if you run `~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel`?

Comment: `No such file or directory`, although I have tried adding multiple potential solutions to my $PATH from other questions.

Comment: Okay, so it's not there. Does `~/.composer/vendor/bin/` exist? If so, does it contain anything?

Comment: That doesn't exist either. Although I have installed composer.

Comment: What does `composer global config bin-dir --absolute` return?

Comment: `Changed current directory to /home/dev/.config/composer
/home/dev/.config/composer/vendor/bin`

Comment: Okay, so that's what you should add to your `PATH`. I'll add an answer. (Do you see `composer` in that directory?)

Comment: `ls -a` returns one directory, `laravel` in that directory.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `laravel`, not `composer`. That's good news!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory that Composer uses to store global binaries can be configured, and its default value depends on your operating system. You can [see what it's set to](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) by running

```
composer global config bin-dir --absolute
```

On your machine that outputs

```
/home/dev/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

so that's what you should add to your `PATH`:

```
export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

See also:

- [Why is COMPOSER_HOME empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38703915/354577), which touches on one reason why you might see `~/.composer/` on some machines and `~/.config/composer/` on others.