# Github Auth token not working in auth.json file Magento 2.4.2

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, magento2, access-token, magento2.2

I have my project in magento 2.3.3 and I am upgrading it to Magento 2.4.2.
In auth.json file I want to add github token generated from the link  `https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+NTZ-CPU-155+2021-04-09+1517`.
But the token is not working when I am adding the same in mu auth.json file.

Error I am getting:

> Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters: "ghp_1nKdhaeIbUzRN2DsrMDkB2kbLXzFcn0jwjhdwhaQyEt"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer \[UnexpectedValueException\] error will trying to use composer to install a github project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691681/composer-unexpectedvalueexception-error-will-trying-to-use-composer-to-install)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Authentication token format updates are generally available](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-31-authentication-token-format-updates-are-generally-available/)",  the format of GitHub authentication tokens has changed.

Notably, the token formats now include the following updates:

- The character set changed from [a-f0-9] to [A-Za-z0-9_]
- The format now includes a prefix for each token type, including `ghp_` for Personal Access Tokens.

That is why composer has [issue 9800](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9800): "Please release a version with updated GitHub token regex"

The resolution is to upgrade composer to 2.0.12 and 1.10.21, which include [commit dc83ba9](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/dc83ba93f3d8a35629f9a387632e8cd373a144d0).

```
 # old regexp
 {^[.a-z0-9]+$}

 # new one
 {^[.A-Za-z0-9_]+$}
```