# "composer install" on the docker container error - UnexpectedValueException Your github oauth token for github.com

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php

Do you know why it shows this error when running composer install? I already tried a lot of commands but nothing is working.

```
 [UnexpectedValueException]
  Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters: "ghp_..."
```

I also tried to add on the auth.json file using http-basic but still doesn't work:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        
        "github.com": {
            "username": "...",
            "password": "ghp_..."
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691681/composer-unexpectedvalueexception-error-will-trying-to-use-composer-to-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691681/composer-unexpectedvalueexception-error-will-trying-to-use-composer-to-install)

Comment: Thanks! Now Im getting I>Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In PackageManifest.php line 122:

  Undefined index: name Script php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1. Do you know why it can be?

Comment: That sounds like a new problem you should post in a new question

Answer (score -1):

You should install git, and zip packages inside the container

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zip`

This way, you will not get the token requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but like that it shows "sh: apt-get: not found".

Comment: Depends on your linux version, you should try yum install then